# App installation in Sony Smart Glass

Tags: android, android-studio, sony-smarteyeglass

I am a budding developer. I want to develop an app for Sony Smart Glass and I have bought the glass already started the process of developing with Android Studio. My question is how can I install the app in Sony Smart Glass? I have tried to read the Sony website but it's not mentioned there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has `USB debugging` somewhere in the settings, then enable it. Then you would be able to run the app from studio or `adb` via usb cable. Or just push your `.apk` into that device and install it even with some file explorer. Even Bluetooth might be an option here if the device supports it.

[This SDK](https://developer.sony.com/develop/wearables/smarteyeglass-sdk/) is probably necessary.

If it has no port through which you could push your `.apk` to that device and it relies only on google play or its specific store (something like samsung used to have), then the only option is to use the store - but it shouldn't be that much restricted.